# ImportError: No module named pynput.keyboard

Tags: python, pip, pynput

I have a problem and I can't find anything to help.The idea is that I can't import pynput. I did the pip install and this is what it shows:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sb.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
  ImportError: No module named pynput.keyboard
```

I tried again pip install pynput and it shows

> Requirement already satisfied

Here is the code, i don't know if it helps but there you go:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
def game():
    keyboard = Controller()
    if key.press():
        s = Sound()
        s.read("Cymatics - Guitar Chord Loop 2 - 128 BPM Dmaj")
        s.play()

print "Welcome to soundboard"
print "You will see a list of sound names, just write the name of it"
print "If you want to stop it type stop"
print "Type start"

start = input()
if start.lower() == "start":
    while True:
        game()
else:
    print "Ups, try again.."
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using python 2 or 3 ?

Comment: I am using 2.7.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you running the file? When you do python3 nameofyourprogram.py you should use pip3 install pynput

Comment: Thank so you, that was the problem.I am a beginner and I didn't knew that, I used pip3 to install it.Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Last time I had this issue, it was because I had installed the module using pip for a given version of python (lets say 2.7), but I was running my script using python 3.6.
Try to check the versions.

Comment: python --version says Python 2.7.10, I don't know how to check the module version

Comment: If you did `pip install pynput`, you can check on which python it is installing it using `pip --version`.