# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pynput.keyboard'; 'pynput' is not a package

Tags: python, cmd, keyboard, keylogger, pynput

I'm trying to build a simple keylogger using the **pynput** library which I've installed using pip,
when I write "import pynput" it compiles fine, but once I add a sub library like mouse or keyboard(
`from pynput.mouse import Controller`) it says that pynput.mouse is not package. I'm a newbie to python and please explain what this error means. Thanks in advance. This is the code:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key,Listener
import logging
file="C:\\Users\\lenovo\\Documents\\log.txt"
logging.basicConfig(filename=file,level=logging.DEBUG,format='%(asctime)s: %(message)s')
def on_press(key):
    logging.info(key)
with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

***AND THIS IS THE ERROR:***

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\pynput.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pynput.keyboard import Key
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\pynput.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pynput.keyboard import Key
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pynput.keyboard'; 'pynput' is not a package
```

Comment: Have you installed pyinput with pip?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named pynput.keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55242218/importerror-no-module-named-pynput-keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is totally ok but the problem is with your environment. Looks like you don't have **pynput** package installed in your working python environment. If you are using **PyCharm** then from the **Terminal**(located on bottom left) run: `pip install pynput`
You can also use windows command prompt if you are using windows to run `pip install pynput`.
To learn more about python virtual env check this link: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html