# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pynput.Keyboard'

Tags: python-3.x, importerror, pynput

I cannot import pynput I did the pip install and this is the error:

```
from pynput.Keyboard import Key
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pynput.Keyboard'
```

and when I try to download it again is says: Requirement already satisfied

Im using python 3.7

this is the code if it helps:

```
from pynput.Keyboard import Key
from pynput.Keyboard import Controller


KeyBoard = Controller()
KeyBoard.press('a')
KeyBoard.release('a')
```

Comment: How do you install by pip? You need to make sure pip's python version should the same with the python you execute the script

Comment: I have pip3.7 @FalldogHsieh

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named pynput.keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55242218/importerror-no-module-named-pynput-keyboard)

Comment: I already tried it @DavidDr90

Comment: @yair are you using `PyCharm` to run this code? Did you try run it directly from command prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

keyboard is lowercase. So your code should be:

```py
from pynput.keyboard import Key
from pynput.keyboard import Controller

KeyBoard = Controller()
KeyBoard.press('a')
KeyBoard.release('a')
```